# Webview shows a blank screen instead of the webpage

Tags: android, webview

i have alt.xml and main.xml, alt.xml has a edittext and a button, main.xml has a webview, whenever i try to load a page with the webview it just loads a blank page. i'll post my code below, thanks in advance.

```
package com.tyran.webviewer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class WebViewer extends Activity {
WebView browser;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.alt);
}
public void selfDestruct(View view) {
loadTime();
}

void loadTime() {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    Editable text = edittext.getText();
    String Tekst = text.toString();
browser.loadUrl(Tekst);
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
loadTime();

return(true);
}
}
{
}}
```

Comment: What is the string from the EditText?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phobos, the text of Edittext is a URL like "http://www.google.com". but magnificently it worked all of a sudden now. Didn't really do anything else than moving around some lines. Now i have a new problem, when it loads google the keyboard does not popup. any ideas? back in the days on another project i got it to popup, but it didn't work with the google search function. no letters appeared when i pressed the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Please add following line in your activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml
    activity
 `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`

I also had same problem but this help me out.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.